# Getting Text From Tweets

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, web-crawler

I am tring to read my tweets from a csv file (which I have downloaded previously), and I am having some problems:

```
sia.list <- searchTwitter('#singaporeair', n=10, since=NULL, until=NULL, cainfo="cacert.pem")  
sia.df = twListToDF(sia.list)  
write.csv(sia.df, file='C:/temp/siaTweets.csv', row.names=F)
```

I am trying to extract the text from the list and the problems is with the third line below:

```
sia.df <- read.csv(file=paste(path,"siaTweets.csv",sep="")) 
sia.list <- as.list(t(sia.df))
sia_txt = sapply(sia.list, function(x) x$getText())
```

console output:

```
   > sia.list <- as.list(t(sia.df))
   > sia_txt = sapply(sia.list, function(x) x$getText())
    Error in x$getText : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the text from a csv file , all you have to do is : `sia_txt <- sia$text` (text being the name of the column in which your text is stored.)

the `x$getText` you've used in `saaply` is a `method` available only to lists which come as result of `searchTwitter()`. Hence you cannot convert a DF back to List and use `getText`. For e.g. do:

`xyz <- searchTwitter("#xyz", n = 100)`

`str(xyz)`

You will see a list of methods applicable. something like:

`$ :Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 17 fields
  ..$ text         : chr "RT @BET: \"Who's left to love the black woman?\" ~ WATCH last night's #BeingMaryJane here:\nhttp://t.co/xiUho1FVQi http://t.co/"| __truncated__
  ..$ favorited    : logi FALSE
  ..$ favoriteCount: num 0
  ..$ replyToSN    : chr(0) 
  ..$ created      : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-03-11 13:28:01"
  ..$ truncated    : logi FALSE
  ..$ replyToSID   : chr(0) 
  ..$ id           : chr "575649378062434304"
  ..$ replyToUID   : chr(0) 
  ..$ statusSource : chr "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
  ..$ screenName   : chr "kookie_kay"
  ..$ retweetCount : num 20
  ..$ isRetweet    : logi TRUE`

`and 51 methods, of which 39 are possibly relevant:
  ..  getCreated, getFavoriteCount, getFavorited, getId, getIsRetweet, getLatitude, getLongitude, getReplyToSID,
  ..  getReplyToSN, getReplyToUID, getRetweetCount, getRetweeted, getRetweeters, getRetweets, getScreenName,
  ..  getStatusSource, **getText**, getTruncated, getUrls, initialize`

Notice the `getText`.

Answer (score 0):

*x$getText()* doesn't really make sense here. Because you are using *sapply()*, each element of *sia.list* is what gets passed to x, and these don't have sub-elements you can access using the $ operator.

What is *getText()*? It's not a function in base r or in the twitteR package. If it's a function from some other package, maybe *getText(x)* is what you want, but it's hard to say without knowing more about where it comes from.