# what is getText function in text-mining? Where does it come from? [r]

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, tm

I am following a text-mining example from Social Media Mining with R by Nathan Dannerman & Richard Heimann : [The Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783281774) . After pulling tweets using `searchTwitter` function, the author uses `sapply` on the `list` to extract the text portion like this:

`rstats <- searchTwitter("#rstats", n = 1000)`

`rstats_list <- sapply(rstats, function (x) x$getText())`

This neatly makes a character vector with only the text portion from the tweets. What is getText() ? I can't find anything on it anywhere - the author has not sufficiently explained. I looked at the `tm` package documentation - nothing! I looked for questions related to this on SO - [Getting Text From Tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829982/getting-text-from-tweets/24832483#24832483) The answerer is asking the same question as I. On Inside-R, I found this: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/gettext but it's not the same as `getText` . Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: It's probably an S4 method defined on `rstats`. Is `isS4(rstats)` true?

Comment: it is false but I think you are right. I did `str(rstats)` and one of the method listed is `getText`. I tried `is.object(rstats)` but it also throws false.

Comment: Did you try lsf.str("package:rstats")? It should list all the functions in that package.

Comment: What if you type `rstats[[1]]$getText` does that show you the function code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getText is an accessor method for the 'status' class, as described here: http://www.inside-r.org/howto/mining-twitter-airline-consumer-sentiment.

Sorry for not clarifying in the text,
Nathan Danneman

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the list "rstats" and if u check it under the values in the environment(in RStudio) it displays each tweet along with all the related information of each individual tweet and displays some access methods beneath each of it. You can check getText() there for grabbing just the text content of each tweet.

Answer (score -2):

`getText()` function use for extract the text content of tweets

Exp:

```
rstats <- searchTwitter("#rstats", n = 1000)

rstats[[1]]$$getText()
```

use **twitteR**  library for Processing tweets data.

some use full function for processing tweets:

```
getScreenName(), getId(), getCreated()
```